# Can i use same distribution profile for both app store and adhoc

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store

I created one distribution profile for app store and i uploaded my app to app store.

Now i want provide my app to customers directly with ad hoc distribution. Is it possible to use same provisioning profile for both.

Comment: No dear it's not possible.

Comment: How to over write my app store app by ad hoc app in my device. Is there any other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

No, Appstore provisioning profile is for AppStore only.

Aslo for an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile you need to select on which device it will run.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that with Ad-Hoc distribution you are limited to 100 devices and their UDIDs must be registered on your developer account

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, you have to create a provisioning profile for each.
the below SS explains the difference between both

[image]